# Facebook MErrorCodes override

Tags: javascript, facebook

there's a script in the mobile version of facebook (touch.facebook.com) that has a function that I would like to override

```
__d('MErrorCodes', [
  'fbt',
  'FBLogger'
], (function (a, b, c, d, e, f, g) {
  var h = {
    loadPageFailed: 876000,
    showPageFailed: 876001,
    uncaughtException: 876002,
    noInternetConnection: 876003,
    badStatusCode: 876004,
    getMessage: function (a) {
      switch (a) {
        case h.loadPageFailed:
          return g._('Connection error');
        case h.noInternetConnection:
          return g._('No Internet Connection');
        case h.showPageFailed:
        case h.uncaughtException:
        case h.badStatusCode:
          return g._('Sorry, something went wrong.');
        default:
          b('FBLogger') ('FIXME').mustfix('Unhandled error code %d', a);
          return g._('Sorry, something went wrong.')
      }
    }
  };
  e.exports = h
}), null);
```

into

```
__d('MErrorCodes', [
  'fbt',
  'FBLogger'
], null);
```

I've tried blocking this script from running on site using adblock then copy/pasting it into tampermonkey and doing my edits then running it and it does successfully work, however after a couple of hours the script name changes letting it pass through adblock, however the function's content stays the same

I've did a bit of research and noticed that __d is a requireJS function however I had zero luck overriding it, any help would be appreciated